# Keys missing in foreach

Tags: php, pdo

Iv'e done this many times but cant figure out what i have done wrong this time.

I'm simply requesting all users via my database handler like this:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);
require_once '../include/DbHandler.php';

$db = new DbHandler();

$user_rows = $db->getAllUsers();

foreach($user_rows as $user)
{
    var_dump($user);
}
```

getAllUsers looks like this:

```
public function getAllUsers()
{
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * from user");

    if ($stmt->execute()) 
    {      
        return $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }
}
```

I assumed that i would be able to get id of each user by just writing $user['id'] and so forth for all attributes of each user. But var_dump of $user reveals that all keys are gone. var_dump of the entire result ($user_rows) shows me that keys are still there for each user.

I've gone through my code where i have done this many many times before and see no obvious difference this time, so i just cant figure out why it isnt working.

Comment: Use `print_r($user_rows)` if it has output.

Comment: Your `getAllUsers()` fetches just the first row. Use something like `fetchAll()` to get all results.

Comment: @aldrin27: the var_dump is only for debugging purpose to show me that the keys are missing.

Comment: @Sirko hmmm your so right, didnt see that one allthough i have been through every line many times to find the "bug" ... thanks ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `fetchAll` PDO function:

http://php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.fetchall.php

```
if ($stmt->execute()) 
{      
    return $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
```

It returns an array of all your elements, and not one.

Comment: @DTH don't worry about this. I have 2 upvotes, and now the votes are zero. there is envy people or something like this. You receive to downvotes too in the question. So don't worry, we are free :)

Answer (score 1):

You're only returning a single row from `getAllUsers` with [`fetch`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php). You're then looping over all *values* inside that row, getting a single value at a time, and you're not paying any attention to its key.

Most likely you're trying to return [`fetchAll`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) to return multiple rows at once.